# iOS : Change value by scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to change the `alpha` value of an `UIView` by scrolling in Up/Down directions via `UIScrollView` , my question is how can I set the alpha value of my view while user scrolls in up or down ? something like UISlider but with UIScrollView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *viewx = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:viewx.frame.size];
    viewx.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [_scrollView addSubview:viewx];


    _scrollView.delegate = self;

}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pointNow = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<pointNow.y) {
        NSLog(@"down");

        _redView.alpha = ???

    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>pointNow.y) {
        NSLog(@"up");
      _redView.alpha = ???

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try setting the alpha value using the percentage that the scrollview is offset from the origin as a gauge, ex:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    _redView.alpha = 1-(scrollView.contentOffset.y/(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height));
}
```

So in this case, if the scrollview is at the top `scrollView.contentOffset.y` == 0, and therefore the alpha == 1, i.e.
`alpha = 1-(0/(contentHeight - scrollViewHeight)) = 1-0 = 1`.

If it's at the bottom, `scrollView.contentOffset.y` == `scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height` (since the content offset won't quite reach the bottom of the content view, but will instead reach the bottom of the content view less the scroll view's height). Therefore the alpha == 0, i.e `alpha = 1 - ((contentHeight - scrollViewHeight)/(contentHeight - scrollViewHeight)) = 1-1 = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the alpha to be based on the position of the scrollview or do you simply want scrolling up to make the view more visible and scrolling down to make it more transparent?

If you want the latter, you can simply add .01 or .1 to the alpha if they scroll up, or subtract if they scroll down.

Example:

```
_redView.alpha = _redView.alpha - 0.1 //in the "down" statement
```

If you want it based on the offset then you need a formula to convert the scrollview's offset to a number between 0.0 and 1.

Example:

```
float alpha = 1 - (self.view.frame.size.width/self.scrollView.contentSize.height)
```